# How does CDO DB maintains identity?

Tags: java, orm, cdo-emf

How does CDO Store maintain/keep identity among its objects?

Comment: Each CDO object has an ID available through cdoID() method. CDO ID's are assigned unique values when objects are committed to a repository.

Comment: It is really helpful. Thank you!